# What is the longest Wordle game?

Tags: optimization, wordle

If you play Wordle in hard mode, with unlimited guesses, then you must solve any puzzle eventually. This is true because there are only a finite number of valid five-letter words, and it is not possible to repeat an incorrect guess in hard mode.

What is the longest possible game of Wordle, if unlimited guesses are allowed, but every guess has to be consistent with the hints from previous guesses?

Here is a valid 19-turn game in hard mode. Is this the longest possible?

1. CILLS
2. DILLS
3. FILLS
4. GILLS
5. HILLS
6. JILLS
7. KILLS
8. LILLS
9. MILLS
10. NILLS
11. PILLS
12. RILLS
13. SILLS
14. TILLS
15. VILLS
16. WILLS
17. YILLS
18. ZILLS
19. BILLS

Comment: Are computer-aided searches acceptable?

Comment: Yes, I assumed that a computer-aided search would be needed. I don't know the answer. Are open questions appropriate for this forum, or should I know the answer before posting?

Comment: It's fine to not know the answer, but you do have to be careful about true [open-ended puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6617/69582) because they're off -topic. It must be theoretically possible to firmly prove optimality. Here, with a limited word list and computers allowed, I think you're fine.

Comment: You could prepend that list with AXLES

Comment: Which word list are you using?

Comment: I am using the same word list that is used in the Wordle app. At least, it claims to be the same list. I will share a link to my version, which is alphabetized and omits the dates. Words marked as common will or have appeared as the secret word of the day. Other words are allowed as guesses but not as the final answer. https://gist.github.com/Radcliffe/4bf75c1f52a610779c9c14859461a376

Comment: Here are some of my thoughts:
1) interpret each word as a vertex in a graph
2) draw an oriented edge from word A to word B if B is a valid guess after guessing A
3) the original problem is now to find the longest path in this graph, such that each word in the path has edges to all subsequent words in that path
4) notice that we're looking for maximum transitive relation
5) which is an NP-hard problem :(
6) [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325332795_Maximal_and_maximum_transitive_relation_contained_in_a_given_binary_relation) describes maxim**al** relation algorithm

Comment: You could prepend by QUEUE followed by AXIAL